# How to use Azure CDN with disabled anonymous blob access?

Tags: node.js, cdn, azure-cdn

Looks like as of August 2023 anonymous access to storage accounts has been disabled.
I am trying to create a CDN which will host javascript file(s) for various corp-wide related apps to use.

Since anonymous access is disabled, how can I give read access to consumers of my Azure CDN?

When trying to view the CDN endpoint (using a browser) i keep getting this error:

```
<Code>PublicAccessNotPermitted</Code>
<Message>Public access is not permitted on this storage account.</Message>
```

I know there are SAS tokens, but they have an expiration, so I dont feel this is a viable solution.

What are viable solutions to resolve this CDN/storage access issue? It seems like disabling anonymous access kind of makes the general use-case for CDN's to be obsolete.

Right now Im kind of at a roadblock and seriously just considering publishing my javascript(s) as a node package.

**Updated**

I have to double check this, but it looks like I got unblocked by adding a adding a System user identity on the CDN with role of Reader.

**Updated (3 days later)**

Upon verifying things today I am not able to access things again on the CDN endpoint. So I am back to the drawing board on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your blob storage endpoint is configured to disallow anonymous read access, you should provide a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token in each request you make to your Azure CDN domain.

By default, anonymous read access is not allowed for blob storage endpoints. If your data should be publicly available, you can explicitly [enable anonymous access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#allow-or-disallow-public-read-access-for-a-storage-account) for the blob storage. To allow public access for a storage account, perform the following steps:

1. Navigate to your storage account in the Azure portal.
2. Go to Settings → Configuration section.
3. Set Blob public access to Enabled and click "Save":

[image: Allow public access setting]

I have just checked one of my storage accounts where anonymous access is enabled and it works as expected with the configuration shown above.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Strangely, I've been unable to enable public access. After successfully saving it, it always resets back to being disabled. Regarding the SAS token, that doesn't seem like an ideal thing for me, as SAS tokens expire, and i wouldnt want consumers of my CDN to append with the token in the url.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar that's strange, do you click the Save button at the top after changing the setting?

Comment: Yes. When i click save i see the successfully saved message or whatever it says. The toggle is reverted back when i click on Refresh. I believe there is some policy on my tenant that is preventing anonymous access to blobs.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar yes, it is possible that your changes are overridden by a custom Azure Policy. It's worth reaching out to your  Azure administrator to confirm this. As it currently stands, Azure still supports anonymous access if it is explicitly enabled.

Comment: Curious if setting up a vnet will solve this issue? The vnet would include the frontdoor/CDN/endpoint and the storage account. Theoretically this should work since all CDN requests go thru the endpoint, right?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar yes, it should be possible by specifying IP restrictions for the storage account, there is a good article here https://gunnarpeipman.com/access-restricted-blob-storage-from-azure-cdn/. I think the "public access" setting would still need to be enabled, but at least you would be able to prevent unwanted networks from accessing the files directly.